# cannot resolve method newTracker (Analytics)

Tags: android, analytics

I'm trying to use google analytics in my project. and the newTracker method cannot be found. Also, I have no need for the ecommerce tracker so I took it out. But now i can't close the statement with getting the error

```
: is expected here''
```

I commented where the error shows up below.

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class AnalyticsTracker1 extends Application {

private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxxx-1";


public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.

}


HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker); //: expected here

        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
            : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : null;
```

Modify your code like this , if trackerID is not equal to any of enum then it should return null. Error is coming as you have not completed second ternary operator.
For second problem I assume that you have imported google analytics jar into your project.
If it is than it wont work.
Solution in that case :

1. remove jar from project.
2. Open SDK manager and > in extras download and install Google Play Service and Google Repository
3. When you are done, got to [Google play service set up page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) at "Add Google Play Services to Your Project" select from dropdown Eclipse or Android Studio and follow the process and add Google Play service project as lib to your own project

4 . add

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
to application tag of your manifest.
and it will work.

I have checked its working now.

Comment: Thanks, that answered one of my questions. Would you happen to know why the newTracker method can't be found?

Comment: I have updated ans for second part as well, please check, I tested method is available now.

Comment: was I supposed to download something or am I support one of the packageson the api? newTracker() is stil unresolved.

Comment: Did you removed google analytics jar  jar file from project ? Yeah.. sdk manager will download and install google play service.

Comment: does this work with play services 7? I have just updated and I cannot resolve GoogleAnalytics or Tracker classes

Comment: yes it works, I have also updated latest, please check imports and make sure you have added google play service as lib project

Comment: @Satty I did update it through the sdk manager where can I find it's the location so I can add it as a lib?

Comment: \android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib, import this project. Then add it as lib.