# Using google Place picker in android project

Tags: android, google-play-services

### *I am trying to learn* [***Google's place picker***](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker)

1. I have used the sample project from here
2. I have linked playservices library for the sample project
3. Resolved all the dependencies

### Problem:

***Some depedencies r not resolved ther are,***

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
```

### Question:

1. How to solve this
2. Should I need to add any other project references

Comment: Please check ans at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197771/cannot-resolve-method-newtracker-analytics/29197927#29197927

Comment: @Satty .... I have google-playservices project . as library project ..... and the tags also in manifest. should i need to add any other projects as library project .... or any-other dependencies to be set-up ?

Comment: Did you added lib project in your project ?

Comment: ok, difficult to guess what is wrong, make sure google service Jar is not present in libs. May be you can try whole process on fresh sample project.

Comment: I hvae also this problem. My project can not resolve PlacePicker.IntentBuilder(); in eclipse. Do you have any sugestion or comment(s)?

Answer (score 12):

follow this way :

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services.

For example:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    }
```

3. Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.
4. Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the toolbar.

Comment: No need to add the whole Google Play Services package. 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'' would be enough.

Comment: can you suggest the latest play services version? This is giving error to me

Comment: "select" button in dialog is disabled.. unable to select location and `onActivityResult` is not get called with `RESULT_OK`

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I had te same problem.

I needed to add `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places` to my project.

in the app's `build.gradle` I added

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.6'
}
```